# LoadError when creating ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to create my first gem and here's its structure:

```
riverbattle
├── lib
│   ├── riverbattle
│   │   ├── base.rb
│   │   ├── colorful.rb
│   │   ├── computer.rb
│   │   ├── constants.rb
│   │   ├── exit_error.rb
│   │   ├── field.rb
│   │   ├── game.rb
│   │   ├── human.rb
│   │   ├── invalid_move_error.rb
│   │   ├── move.rb
│   │   ├── player.rb
│   │   ├── version.rb
│   │   └── victory_error.rb
│   └── riverbattle.rb
└── riverbattle.gemspec
```

When I am in the directory `rivarbattle/lib/riverbattle` and I run the command `ruby base.rb`, everything starts working as it should be.

The file `base.rb` is here:

```
require './game'
game = Game.new.start
```

But when I try to run it from the `lib` directory using command `ruby riverbattle.rb`, it fails with the following error:

> /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- riverbattle/base
>   (LoadError)   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from riverbattle.rb:1:in `'

The file `lib/riverbattle.rb` look like this:

```
require 'riverbattle/base'
```

Despite the fact that the load fails I tried to build the gem with the following .gemspec file:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require "riverbattle/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
    s.name          = 'riverbattle'
    s.date          = '2015-07-04'
    s.summary       = 'Enjoy the game!'
    s.description   = 'A small simple game called the Riverbattle'
    s.platform      = Gem::Platform::RUBY
    s.version       = '0.1.0'
    s.authors       = ["Denis Yakovenko"]
    s.email         = ["yakovenko.denis.a@gmail.com"]
    s.require_paths = ["lib"]
    s.license       = "MIT"
end
```

After the successful build, I went to irb and tried `require 'riverbattle'` and got the error:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- riverbattle
>
> from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from (irb):1    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `'

---

1) What am I doing wrong with `require` that the files from different directories cannot be loaded? (After looking through stackoverflow questions I figured out that this is some problem with $LOAD_PATH, but I couldn't find out how to fix the code. BTW, such `require` LoadErrors happen quite often for some reason and then I try to use `require_relative` and sometimes it helps)

2) When I tried to lauch the gem in irb, the error was raised because of those initial problems with `require`, right? Or something else is wrong?

3) If I want to add tests folder to the gem, can I just add the folder `tests` to the root directory and copy all the rspec files there?

### UPDATE

When I tried to run `RUBYLIB="." ruby riverbattle.rb` in the terminal in the `lib` folder, it gave me this:

> RUBYLIB="." ruby riverbattle.rb
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./field (LoadError)     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from
>   /home/denis/WEB/Bursa/riverbattle/lib/riverbattle/game.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from
>   /home/denis/WEB/Bursa/riverbattle/lib/riverbattle/base.rb:1:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from riverbattle.rb:1:in `'

Comment: might help https://shivab.com/blog/ruby/2019/08/30/convert-your-ruby-script-to-a-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
`#require` tries to load an absolute path, and if it fails it loads from `$:`, to add your current directory run the script like this (bash, otherwise use apropriate method to define environment variables for your shell):

```
RUBYLIB="." ruby riverbattle.rb
```

In your `base.rb` require as follows:

```
require 'riverbattle/game'
```

2.
*see #UPD section*

3.
why wouldn't you? (what's your [specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with this?)

### #UPD

The 2nd issue is because you miss [`#files`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files) in your gem specification, no files are included in your gem file, add something like this:

```
s.files = Dir['lib/*.rb'] + Dir['lib/riverbattle/*.rb']
```

### #UPD2

Just to summarize [here](http://pastebin.com/aeE12A5H) is working setup for your gem.

Comment: 1. I tried running this command in my terminal from the `lib` folder and it gave me even longer error (please, see in updates of the question).
If I change my `require` in `base.rb` it just stops working, I mean the correct path should be `require './game'`, 'cause the current directory the for `base` file is `lib/riverbatle`
2. Nope, I did install the gem:) Do you think that's only problem with my computer and if I install the gem on another one, it may actually work properly?

Comment: When you `require './game'` it looks from current directory, your path resolves to `lib/game.rb` which is not there, when you `require 'riverbattle/game'` it resolves to `[path to your gem directory]/lib/riverbattle/game.rb` because [the `lib` directory is added to the load path by rubygems](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#requiring-code).