# Cannot require ruby files from a directory other then the one with main files (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

My problem is the following:

I can't require a ruby file from any directory other than the one with all the main files, i.e. `require`s like this: `./file` work fine, but `require`s like this: `dir_name/file` fail.

Here's my project structure:

```
├── bin
│   ├── console
│   └── setup
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── Gemfile
├── lib
│   ├── riverbattle
│   │   ├── base.rb          <------- main file that starts everything
│   │   ├── colorful.rb
│   │   ├── computer.rb
│   │   ├── constants.rb
│   │   ├── exit_error.rb
│   │   ├── field.rb
│   │   ├── game.rb
│   │   ├── human.rb
│   │   ├── invalid_move_error.rb
│   │   ├── move.rb
│   │   ├── player.rb
│   │   ├── version.rb
│   │   └── victory_error.rb
│   └── riverbattle.rb  <------ the file from where I get the error
├── LICENSE
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
├── spec
│   ├── spec_helper.rb
│   └── riverbattle_spec.rb
├── riverbattle-0.1.2.gem
└── riverbattle.gemspec
```

So, when I launch the app like this: `ruby base.rb` when I am in the `lib/riverbattle/` directory, everything launches fine, but when I try to do `ruby riverbattle.rb` from the directory `lib/`, I get the following error:

> ➜  lib git:(master) ✗ ruby riverbattle.rb
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./field (LoadError)     from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/riverbattle-0.1.2/lib/riverbattle/game.rb:1:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/riverbattle-0.1.2/lib/riverbattle/base.rb:1:in`
>   '    from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'   from
>   /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'   from riverbattle.rb:2:in `'

I just don't get it why it cannot require one single file.
By the way, here's the content of the file (`riverbattle.rb`) from which I get the error:

```
require "riverbattle/version"

module Riverbattle
  require "riverbattle/base"
end
```

and nothing else.

I was told that `require` actually requires an absolute path to the file and I need to do something with my $LOAD_PATH or something, but this information doesn't help at all to solve the issue. Why is it okay to require files from the same directory, but not okay, if I require them from another one?

---

1) Could anybody help me with solving that problem?

2) Is it the problem with only my computer and I can safely publish it as a gem (i.e. it may work properly on another computer), or it is the wrong code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` searches in your `$LOAD_PATH`. `require` should generally be used if you want to use a gem that is installed on your system. For your purposes you want to use `require_relative`:

```
require_relative 'riverbattle/version'
```

Note that at first glance

```
require './riverbattle/version'
```

might also seem to work. However, `.` here points to the current directory from where you run the process, not the directory where the file resides, obviously this is not what you want.

Comment: "require should generally be used if you want to use a gem that is installed on your system. " <-- this is the most important phrase for me for today.
I've changed every single `require` in my project to `require_relative` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

If `lib/base.rb` is your main file, then perhaps it should be the "executable" file?  If that is the case, should it be in bin?

`$LOAD_PATH` can be added to by using `-I` option with the ruby executable.

`ruby -Ipath_to_project_root/lib lib/main.rb`

would then let any file that requires files in your project look in the lib folder.

It can also be used like the answer in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226470/485864) with the `$:` or `$LOAD_PATH`.

Look at how other gems are set up, and you will find that your base.rb file can live in the bin folder, just like your setup and console files are.  If it is the main script that starts it all, it could be named `riverbattle` as is common with gems to have an executable of the same or similar name.

`require` is not used to load gems, it is used to load files and without any explicit path given, will look in the load path.  It doesn't matter if it is a gem or not.

`require_relative` is used to load files that are always local relative to the file that is using the `require_relative` method.

Of course, the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require) is your friend.